# react router history.push not loading expected component

Tags: reactjs, redirect, router, saga

I am using saga for managing my async call.

Here is login saga :

```
export function* loginApi({ type, formObj }) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(formObj).map(key => {
        formData.append(key, formObj[key]);
    })
    const response = yield axios.post(`http://localhost/coupon/web/api/login`, formData)
    if (response.data.status) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.data.token);
        yield put(loginsuccess(response.data.data.token))
        yield call(forwardTo, '/dashboard')
    } else {
        yield put(loginFaield(response.data.msg))
    }
}
```

After login successful I want redirect user to dashboard so for that:

`yield call(forwardTo, '/dashboard')` which execute forwardTo function and below is implementation of it:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
function forwardTo(location) {
    console.log('location', location);
    history.push(location);
}

export default forwardTo;
```

It change my url from `http://localhost:3000/login` to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` but it shows login page instead of dashboard.

Routes :

```
const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/register" component={RegisterUser} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in the Login Component...

After the saga does this `yield put(loginsuccess(response.data.data.token))`
Now I assume.. some data regarding login successful is stored. Say `state.user.token` is `null` before login, after login it has some value.

Do change your Login Component to look like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {compose} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const Login = props => {
  return (
    <div>
    /*all login UI */
    //..
    {
      props.token ? 
      <Redirect to={'/dashboard'}/> : null
    }
    </div>
  ) 
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    token: //state.user.token or whatever
});

export default compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(Login);
```

---

When user is not logged in the `token` value is `null` so it renders nothing but when login is successful, some value assigned to token, as the result `<Redirect to='/dashboard'/>` will be rendered and the site will be redirected to `/dashboard`

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new history each time you invoke createHistory(), try to add this function to the app so that it's fired once the app is running and add `exact` property for all your routes

```
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterUser} />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
```

Comment: I have added exact to all routes but still facing same issue

Comment: I encourage you to use `withRouter` HOC instead  of history

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem a few days ago.

I think you have created Router with BrowserRouter.
If so, you should change it to default Router and add history.

Do it like below code.

`history.tsx`

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

`store.tsx`

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
// You can add middleware here...
```

`App.tsx`

```
import { FC } from "react";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import history from '../utils/history';

interface FuncProp {}

const AppRouter: FC<FuncProp> = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home">
          <p>HomePage</p>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*">
          <p>Page not found. (404)</p>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```